# Android: dialog animation stops working when dialog called from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, dialog, android-dialogfragment

Good day. I faced problem, when dialog animation stops working when dialog called from fragment.
First I tried DialogFragment with custom style:

```
    public static class QRDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        ImageView im = new ImageView(getActivity());
        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.qr_code_placeholder);

        im.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        im.setClickable(true);
        im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        im.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.setView(im);
        return dialog.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.XSlideAnimation;
    }
}
```

Those XSlideAnimation is simple animation style:

```
    <style name="XSlideAnimation" >
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/slide_out_right</item>
    </style>
```

It didn't work.

Then I tried set custom animation for fragment transaction:

```
    FragmentTransaction tr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tr.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
            new QRDialog().show(tr, "dialog");
```

in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="500"
        />
</set>
```

out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="50%"
        android:duration="500"
        />
</set>
```

No success either.

Then I tried just to get new Dialog instance and set animation for it:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        ImageView im = new ImageView(getActivity());
        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.qr_code_placeholder);

        im.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        im.setClickable(true);
        im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        im.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        dialog.setContentView(im);
        im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.XSlideAnimation;
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
```

And animation works perfect BUT only if I call dialog from activity. When I put exact same code in fragment, animation stop working. First approach works from activity too, but not in fragment.

How can I get working animation when creating dialog in fragment?

**UPD 16-102017:**
I see no answer or comments here so far, but somebody upvoted this issue once. So, just for update - in my case it's just started to work. I did literally nothing with code. Animation just appeared and staid couple days later during tests.